# Como renderizar una constante?

Tags: reactjs

puedo renderizar una constante?

```
const myTitle = <h1>hello world</h1>;

class TodoApp extends Component {
  render() {

    return (myTitle)
  }
}
```

quiero renderizar esta constante myTitle

solo renderiza si esta solo, y si quiero poner un div que lo envuelva ya deja de funcionar

```
let myList= (<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ul>);

ReactDOM.render(<di>myList</div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

se puede hacer eso?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo:

```
const myTitle = <h1>hello world</h1>;

export default function App() {
  return myTitle
}
```

Te recomiendo que mires la página oficial, hay buena documentación: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: osea debo ponerlo si o si en un compoenente?

Comment: Lo puedes poner en un componente, en otra constante, en una funcion...

Comment: edite mi pregunta, respondeme de nuevo porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Échale un vistazo a este artículo de la documentación oficial:

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

En ReactJS puedes, dentro del return (o render), decidir si un componente se renderiza o no si se cumple o no una condición. Es muy útil para este tipo de casos.